# plot a hi res compass rose in matlab

Tags: matlab

I'm trying to figure out how to plot a 1-degree resolution compass rose in matlab, that looks something similar to this:

[image]

I have tried various compass and polar plots but they don't seem to allow customizing the appearance of the scale around the plot.  I can only get a basic 30 degree grid.

Update/Answers to comments:

I'm building a map using azimuthal prjection:

ax=axesm ('eqdazim', 'Frame', 'on', 'Grid', 'on')

this generates a vector image like this:

[image: globe]

the next step is to add the shapeimage (which I already figured out) and a compass grid around it.

I want to generate a high quality/large print so I'm trying to stay in the vector format

But this does not need to be done in matlab, if there is a better tool for it.  I just thought it would be easier to do the whole thing in one package. No experience with LaTeX but will look into it.  A quick/scriptable process is important.

Comment: Do you want to use this exact appearance with a polar plot? In this case you could use it as a background image for your plot instead of customizing what's already there.

Comment: @knedlsepp, thats only a partial solution. Vector graphics, such as Matlab plots, tend to be crisp at any scale (Because they are re-rastered each time you zoom). But putting an image would not look as good as that.

Comment: @Andrey: True. I guess it depends on the OP's priorities on beautiful plots, but this could be a pragmatic approach.

Comment: @k3it: How are you planning to use this plot? Web, TeX print, other? Is there any specific reason for matlab?

Comment: @knedlsepp, yes I think you're right, it is a feasible approach

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could play with the options of

- [Advanced Polar Plots v2](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/22859-advanced-polar-plots-v2)
- [Comprehensive Polar Plots](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/38855-comprehensive-polar-plots)

from the File Exchange.

e.g.: Advanced Polar Plots v2:

```
pp(0:1,0:1,'ThetaDirection', 'cw', ...
           'ThetaStartAngle', 270, ...
           'AngleStep', 1, ...
           'AngleLabelStep', 10, ...
           'AngleAxisStyle', '.', ...
           'RingAxis', 'off')
```

Comment: could you provide an example of creating an empty plot with just the 'theta' scale, one degree ticks and ten degree labels?